# Need clarification for duplicate questions

Tags: discussion

This question marked as duplicate " https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83870/how-do-i-solve-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away " , but that question also don't have any answers, So it will be going to ask by anyone again and again, since it don't have any answer. why it marked as duplicate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a duplicate question from the same user, asked 19 hours ago.

Keeping it open provides no value to the site, and will teach the user that asking duplicate questions is fine, which obviously it's not.

The limitation on closing questions as duplicate when they have no answers doesn't extend to users asking duplicates of their *own* questions, and definitely not within 24 hours of the original.

I've explained to the OP that we differ from a support forum, and to concentrate updates and efforts on the original question, which is the desired result here IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is the same question asked twice. In fact the error shown in both the cases is the same.

> Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception. Original PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT nt.* FROM {node_type} nt WHERE (disabled = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY nt.type ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 0 ) in _node_types_build() (line 739 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\node\node.module). Additional PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT ff.* FROM {filter_format} ff WHERE (status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY weight ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in filter_formats() (line 427 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\filter\filter.module). Uncaught exception thrown in session handler. PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in _drupal_session_write() (line 209 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\session.inc).

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT nt.* FROM {node_type} nt WHERE (disabled = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY nt.type ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 0 ) in _node_types_build() (line 738 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\node\node.module).

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT ff.* FROM {filter_format} ff WHERE (status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY weight ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in filter_formats() (line 427 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\modules\filter\filter.module).

In this case, the questions have been asked from the same user, but the question would have been closed even in the case the questions were asked from two users. What would we do if 10 people are trying to resolve the same issue, and they all use *Drupal Answers*? Should we accept 10 different questions asking how to resolve the same issue?

The fact the duplicated question doesn't have any answer is not an excuse for asking the question again, especially when the first question has been asked less than 24 hours ago. It would not be an excuse even if the same question was asked 6 months ago.

If nobody knows the answer, then nobody will know the answer even if the same question is asked more than once. What could happen is that, eventually, the second question is clearer, and somebody will answer it correctly. If that is the case, then it would be the first question to be closed as duplicate of the second question, since Stack Exchange prefers that the question without answers is closed as duplicate of the question with at least an answer.

Comment: ( @clive please look in to this) I agree if the user is same, but what is the solution for the question ? , since it don't have any answer, users will constantly ask the same question, until they find the answer for it.

Comment: The user who asked the question is irrelevant, since asking the same question more than once doesn't make it answerable, nor does it make a user answer it. If somebody knew the answer would have answered it when the question was asked.

Comment: @Bala this usually does not happen if user provides data he is asked for in comments. If he refuses to provide that data, it's his problem. If another user can provide more data, question will not be marked as a duplicate (or he can ask again with new information, if he didn't provide them in the first place - new question would be safe then).

Comment: @Bala If they keep asking the same question, even after the rules about duplicates have been explained (remember, these are site _rules_, not an opinion held by a few people or anything like that), then we'll just keep closing the question up to the point where it becomes useless to do so any more. Then we're into the realm of banning the user instead; what you're describing, to continually post the same question, is an abuse of the site, and we simply won't allow it to happen :)